# Active Admin hide menu based in subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

There's a way to hide menu based on subdomain?

I tried to get subdomain in request in ApplicationController and store it as global variable to use in the resource, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#customize-the-menu) has an example for how to do this.

Using the information you've given, this might solve your problem:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Custom1 do
  menu parent: "basic_entities", if: proc { request.subdomain == "foo" }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example like, below

```
require 'domainatrix'
url = Domainatrix.parse("#{request.host}") #=> test.example.com, will change based on request
subdomain = url.subdomain           # => "test.example"
if subdomain == 'test.example'
   // Your code staff like hiding menu
elsif subdomain == 'test1.example'
   // Your code staff like hiding menu
 // more ...
else
  // Show menu
end
```

I think will help

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I have another problem, I need to do it based on my current subdomain, and the subdomain is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

you can use `request.subdomains` in your controller which return an array of current  request subdomains 
[subdomain docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-subdomain) for more info

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my problem is this

`ActiveAdmin.register Custom1 do
  menu parent: "basic_entities" # I need to filter visibility here

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      # I only have access to request.subdomains here
      end_of_association_chain.for_account(current_account)
    end
  end
end`

How to deal with it?